# Primal Groudon Not Reappearing in Omega Ruby after blacking out

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

So after I got to the point in Omega Ruby where I had to catch primal groudon, I simply couldn't and after trying to catch it for about two hours, I gave up and let it black me out, so I could train more. When I went back to the cave of origin to catch it, it would not give me the cutscene where I ride on it's back and go to the other room to catch it. Is there anyway to fix this other than starting a new file?

Comment: Have you tried completely exploring the Cave of Origin? When I first explored it, I noticed a blocked path. My guess is that path is now free and leads to Groudon/Kyogre.

Comment: Yeah, I checked around a bit and found a side path that was blocked originally and led me into groudon's area. Thank you!

Comment: @Nolonar you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 2):

When you first visited the Cave of Origin, you might have noticed a T-junction.

[image: Cave of Origin: T-junction]
<sub>Image from [serebii.net](http://www.serebii.net/pokearth/hoenn/caveoforigin.shtml)</sub>

Before meeting Groudon or Kyogre, the left road lead to a dead end. After the riding cutscene, the path should lead to the [version mascot](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Version_mascot) of the [weather trio](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Weather_trio).